# gcc -print-multi-os-directory error on mac

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, compiler-errors

My mac version is Sierra. Xcode 8.0

gcc info

`Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin`

I think gcc is not problem. My project build option is `-print-multi-os-directory`. but my gcc unsupported... what's the problem???

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on mac your `GCC` is `Clang` as you may see in output

in clang option `-print-multi-os-directory` is unsupported

[On current trunk (line 2079)](https://reviews.llvm.org/diffusion/L/browse/cfe/trunk/include/clang/Driver/Options.td)
[Was marked as unsupported here](https://reviews.llvm.org/rL241708)

You may try to  install pure `gcc` via `brew install gcc` command

Also why do you need this option? Do you have any special checks in you project ?([this option just print path](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/doc/invoke.texi?r1=153058&r2=153057&pathrev=153058) )

Since you are trying to build binutils:
https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=bfd/configure;h=97693870c462d5e5231bd2b512a76b7c271b9133;hb=7fa393306ed8b93019d225548474c0540b8928f7#l10348
Try to figure out why you get in condition when multi-os option is used.

This happened because your compiler passed test:

Comment: I don't know.. I build binutils. It have to that option.. Thansk for answer

Comment: Please add link to binutils that you are building, and also configure options. Most likely binutils are supported mac OS

Comment: Thanks!. I finished compile for your help. :D